# SqlDependency throwing Invalid Operation exception

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, global-asax, sqldependency

In our project we are invalidating the cache based on the change in the query output. This is implemented using change notifications.

In the `Global.asax` file in the `Application Start` block we have also added `SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionStr)`. But still its throwing the following invalid operation exception:

> Message "When using SqlDependency without providing an options value,
>   SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command
>   added to the SqlDependency instance." string

What could be the possible reason for this issue?

Comment: You have looked at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/0f77c989-d6de-49bf-9e4c-d24a60c0160f ?